# Why the difference of two sets gives result sometimes with proper sequence and sometimes not in python?

Tags: python, set

I wondered while performing some set related operation.
below is my scenario,
I have two sets 'a' and 'b', and I'm calculating the difference.

```
a = {1,2,3,5}
b = {5,6,7,8}
print(b-a)
```

and I have another two set 'c' and 'd' and same, I'm calculating the difference of that two sets also.

```
c = {1,2,3,4,0}
d = {6,7,8,9,5}

print(d-c)
```

The result of above two operations is like :

```
{8, 6, 7}          #Expecting {6,7,8}, why this sequence changed ?
{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

But here I found that the sequence of the first result is changed.
while other is in the correct sequence.

Comment: Sets are unordered.

Comment: Sets are fundamentally unordered.  `{6,7,8}` is the same as `{8,6,7}`.

Comment: But why for the second scenario its gives correct order ?

Comment: For the second scenario, you are just lucky.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

> A set is an **unordered** collection with no duplicate elements. Basic uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries.